# vpn l2tp connection on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, networkmanager

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and I need to create a VPN L2TP connection.

I installed strongswan, as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/578881/351927), but now I don't understand how to configure the connection.

The connection data I have available are an Ip address, a username, a password and a preshared key.

I try to create the connection using the network manager, but I don't understard which option I have to select. First thing: do I have to create an ipsec/ikev2 or a pptp vpn? Which authentication protocol do I have to select? Where do I insert my preshared key?

Any help is appreciated